# MySQL - Is it possible to achieve this using SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

Imagine you've got a table with 2 columns: ID and NAME. ID is simply a number, incrementing for each row (as you'd expect). NAME is some random varchar string. NAME can be same for different rows. Now, imagine you want to get the 3 latest occurences in this table, where NAME only may occur once.

For example, if you've got this data:

```
ID  NAME
1   HELLO
2   TEST
3   HELLO
4   HELLO
5   QWERTY
6   HELLO
```

Then the result of the question should be:

```
6   HELLO
5   QWERTY
2   TEST
```

Is it possible achieve this on SQL level?

Comment: Please rename the question to something like `Get latest occurrences of text` so similar questions are minimized and it's easier for someone to find this solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   MAX(ID), 
   Name
FROM 
   table
GROUP BY 
   Name
ORDER BY
   MAX(ID) desc
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT MAX(ID), NAME
FROM THAT_TABLE
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

See: [GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: You need to add `LIMIT 3` to the end of that.

Comment: I just re-read the question. Macy's answer is closer and better!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you need to use "DISTINCT" for the "name" column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, id FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Another way to achieve this is to use "GROUP BY" for "name" (see another answer)